# Array in javascript like php

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I'm trying to make a array in javascript like I can make in php. In php i can make a array like this and then insert in whatever index I like

```
$p = array();
$p["abcd"] = "James";
```

Now I want this functionality in js. Is it possible to do it in js

I have done something like this but this is throwing me an error

```
$.each( $('table[data-step-id=' + step_id +'] input[name^=actions]') , function(key , value){
    debugger;
    steps_actions_dates_assign[key]["action"].push(value.val());
});
```

this is the error
   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined`

**MY QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

I'm not trying to access a php array in javascript but I'm trying to make a array in javascript like php(the way we do not have to worry about indexes the same way I should be able to add any index I want)

**THIS IS ALL OF THE CODE**

```
var steps_actions_dates_assign = new Array();

$.each($('.steps-table') , function (key , value){
    debugger;
    step_id = value.children[0].value;
    steps_actions_dates_assign[key]["action"] = new Array();
    $.each( $('table[data-step-id=' + step_id +'] input[name^=actions]') , function(key , value){
        debugger;
        steps_actions_dates_assign[key]["action"].push(value.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: The person who down voted my question can he/she please explain why was this question downvoted ??

Comment: @J Doe, this basic you will be able get from book itself, try to lean by your self first then ask

Comment: Just seen your edit, which makes of this an entirely new question. You think `steps_actions_dates_assign[key]` is an object: it isn't. Use your debugger to find out what it is.

Comment: Should be closed, as it is question "Why is my code not working..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are designed for numeric indexes and hold ordered data.

Use objects to store properties with arbitrary names.

```
var p = {};
p["abcd"] = "James";
```

In JS, an array is a kind of object so it is *possible* to store arbitrary properties on it, but you will run into problems when you attempt to iterate over the array or pass it to functions such as `JSON.stringify`.

If you are using ES6 than [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) are another option.

Comment: Hum, I had forgotten maps. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) they keep track of insertion order so they might be an alternative under certain circumstances.

Comment: @JDoe — That's pretty much an entirely new question, and it isn't answerable in it's current state anyway. You don't show us what `steps_actions_dates_assign` is or why you expect `steps_actions_dates_assign[key]` to be defined.

Comment: @JDoe — The error message says that `steps_actions_dates_assign[key]` is undefined. Since you have never defined it (`steps_actions_dates_assign` is an empty array), that is to be expected. Define it